# Job count does not make sense

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Behold the [jobs](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/egnyte):

[image]

but the company sidebar shows:

[image]

> You had one job!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this is okay. Since you can be listed without current offers check [ByteLabor](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/bytelabor-co-kg) as example there are no open jobs.